# jQuery: Element is not clicked during test execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

```
describe('When a user selects a single-response Hotspot response', function () {

        it('Then should highlight the selection', function () {
            utils.clickHotspotElementAtIndex(view, 0, function() {
            });
            expect(view.$('.lrn_selected')[0]).toExist();
        });
```

**--------utils helper methods are defined below----------**

```
const utils = _.extend({}, baseQuestionHelper.utils, {
        isReactiveViews: baseQuestionHelper.utils.isReactiveViews(hotspotBundle, 'hotspot'),
        getHotspotElementAtIndex: function (view, index) {
            return view.$('polygon').eq(index).get(0);
        },
        clickHotspotElementAtIndex: function (view, index, callback) {
            syn.click(utils.getHotspotElementAtIndex(view, index), null, callback);
            console.log('clicked on a hotspot');
        }
```

My jasmine test case is written as above, its expected test flow is simple:

- click on a Hotspot element at index 0
- when this Hotspot element is clicked, it will have a new class `lrn_selected` assigned.
- Verify this clicked Hotspot element has its class name as `lrn_selected`

When executed, I did get this debugging console log `clicked on a hotspot`. But, this script will fail with the following error message:

- Uncaught Expected undefined to exist. which suggests the hotspot element is not clicked.

Why was it not clicked?

Comment: What does your `utils.getHotspotElementAtIndex(view, index)` return? Does the _ polygon_ exist?
Can you show the code where the class _lrn_selected_ is added to your element?